# How to manage long integer value in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a id parameter in the url and it looks like

```
http://localhost/project/index.php?id=20234532
```

The problem is this number can be grown up to a bigger number within few days.

First thought : If there is any way to remove the id value from url using htaccess then that's fine.Not sure though.

Second thought : If the value 20234532 can be encoded in a shorter value and then decode again.

I can't think of any other possible idea now.Also I can't use post method as this id will come in the url always.

Apologies, if I put the question in wrong place as clearly it is not an issue rather seeking for solution.

Comment: Why is it in the url? What does it represent?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with a long number in the URL? And your definition of "long" most likely isn't anywhere near the length the parameters used by major companies.

Comment: @gurinderhans It's in the url because I need to do $_GET to get the id.I can't use session or post method.

Comment: @PatrickQ Actually I have never seen any url containing a very long integer.

Comment: Consider that $_GET in PHP contains always strings, so even if your number is big, you have no problem about url. If you want to reduce that, maybe you should split it in 2 values, depending on what that number means.

Comment: Yes we cant help a lot unless we know exactly what that number means

Comment: Have you never used the internet? The number that you gave is the same number of digits as the ID of this question. Just look in your address bar.  Do any simple Google search and you're bound to see a bunch of crazy long URLs (especially if you click a paid result).

Comment: @FedericoReghenzani That's a good idea.So you mean I can do like this param1=2023&param2=4532

Comment: That is a terrible idea if that actually represents an ID. If you're really that concerned about how long it is, convert it to alphanumeric.

Comment: @gurinderhans That number is generated from a database table and the id is autoincrement with primary key.

Comment: No, the problem is you will have a too big table, so if you need more than 32 bit (standard int in PHP), you have more than 2^32 rows in your table...

Comment: @FedericoReghenzani Sorry I couldn't understand.

Comment: You say that `id` is a primary key of a table. Then, if that field is an int, this limits the maximum value of `id`.

Comment: Thanks @FedericoReghenzani got it now.In one post I was looking for 32 bit integer and it was something like xxx-xxxx-xxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of things you can do here. You can convert it to base 32, and make the URL even short by using mod_rewrite:

```
$id = (whatever comes out of database)
$shortID = base_convert($id,10,32);
```

Then use the `$shortID` to make the URL: `http://example.com/$shortID`, so maybe something that looks like `http://example.com/a5pqnf3k` (that's ID = 349832985716).

Then in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?shortID=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then when you check the "shortID" you'd just reverse it to get the long ID:

```
$shortID = $_GET['shortID'];
$id = base_convert($shortID,32,10);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon.This is the solution which I was eagerly looking for.Thank you so much for your help.